# MySQL server 8.0.23 not using a index

Tags: mysql

I have 2 instances of MySQL server (8.0.23).  One is running in our stage environment and the other is running in our production environment. They both has the same indexes created.  I execute exactly the same query in both but the query plan is indicating different a full table scan in our development environment but it uses a key in our stage environment.

The query I am executing is

```
select max(ac.customerId),max(c.firstName),max(c.lastName) from account_customers ac 
    join customers c on c.id = ac.customerId 
    where ac.lookupAccountId = 123
    and c.emailAddress like '%wsadiq%'
    group by ac.customerId
    order by c.lastName asc;
```

In both instances, there is a non-unique key on lookupAccountId and customerId.

When this query is run in our stage environment, the execution plan indicates the server utilizing key on lookupAccountId and customerId.  However, when this query is run on the production instance, the server does a full table scan instead of using the lookupAccountId.

Any idea why that is and what can I do to ensure that the server uses the lookupAccountId key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: like and % make always a ful table scan

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Why does the server not do a full table scan in stage environment.  I also ran the same query in a different instance with millions of rows and the server did not do a full table scan in that third system either.

Comment: Like with first char is % cant use index. a index is a sorted list of the vals and % all vals, so they cant use them

Comment: It makes sense.  But now I am confused as to why the other 2 servers show indexes being used.  Also mind you, there is no index on the field that is using like.  The 2 instances that are using index are using the index on lookupAccountId to narrow down the rows.  See the image at https://www.dropbox.com/s/o16ic4cjo61mnn2/Screen%20Shot%202021-08-12%20at%2012.02.15%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: *Why does the server not do a full table scan in stage environment.* It uses the index not as ordered list but as compact copy of the table. I.e. it uses fullscan of the index instead of fullscan of the table.

Comment: I guess my question is why 1 out of three instances using the exact same version of the server and exact same structure of the tables are executing the same query differently.  One of the 2 servers that is using the lookupAccountId index has several million rows of customers.

Comment: see how mqany rows you have on all three servers and also try to use hint. another possibility is tio try more indexes combined and test these

Comment: Providing a hint seemed to be a good idea.  After I provided the hint, the query optimizer used that index and using that index caused about 33% saving.  Thanks.